# Get activities of user based on user id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am looking to fetch activities of [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) based on their user id. I can see that there is a [Get user activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/projectrome-get-activities?view=graph-rest-1.0) API to get my activities but is there any way to get activity of other users? Given the fact that i have admin account and i can assign permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the activity of other users you can use this API

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/activities
```

It requires `UserActivity.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp` permission.